# WHere does my hardcore character go after dying in a special league?

Tags: path-of-exile

If my character dies in the default hardcore league, it goes to the standard league.
If I die while I am playing in the special hardcore league (Talisman right now) does my character get moved to the special normal league, or to the standard league?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any hardcore character that dies is moved to standard, regardless of the specific hardcore league.

There is no way to go from one special league to another.

Comment: You can link this file http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/File:Leagues.png for visual explanation.